# Combine the value of attribute and element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Is it possible to combine the value of attribute to the value of element?

INPUT XML

```
<Files>
<File>
    <Data1>
        <item attrib="Ol4d">value1</item>
    </Data1>
    <Data2 attrib="Old"/>
    <Data3>
        <item attrib="New">value2</item>
    </Data3>
</File>
<File attrib="New">
    <Data1>
        <item2>
           <item3 attrib="Old">value3</item3>       
        </item2>
    </Data1>
</File>
<File attrib="New">
    <Data1>
        <item attrib="Old">value1</item>
    </Data1>
</File>
</Files>
```

Say if it matches an element with specific attribute such as "Old", result will be like below.

DESIRED OUTPUT XML

```
<Files>
<File>
    <Data1>
        <item attrib="Old">Old-value1</item>
    </Data1>
    <Data2 attrib="Old"/>
    <Data3>
        <item attrib="New">value2</item>
    </Data3>
</File>
<File attrib="New">
    <Data1>
        <item2>
           <item3 attrib="Old">Old-value3</item3>       
        </item2>
    </Data1>
</File>
<File attrib="New">
    <Data1>
        <item attrib="Old">Old-value1</item>
    </Data1>
</File>
</Files>
```

CURRENT XSLT

I originally got this

```
<xsl:template match="*[@attrib='Old' and normalize-space(.)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:text>replace value</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then replaced xsl:text with <xsl:value-of select="@attrib" separator="-"/> but it is not combining with the value of the element, just replacing it with the attribute value.

OUTPUT produced by XSLT:

```
<Files>
   
   <File>
      
      <Data1>
         
         <item attrib="Old">Old</item>
         </Data1>
      
      <Data2 attrib="Old"></Data2>
      
      <Data3>
         
         <item attrib="New">value2</item>
         </Data3>
      </File>
   
   <File attrib="New">
      
      <Data1>
         
         <item2>
            
            <item3 attrib="Old">Old</item3>       
            </item2>
         </Data1>
      </File>
   
   <File attrib="New">
      
      <Data1>
         
         <item attrib="Old">Old</item>
         </Data1>
      </File>
   </Files>
```

Comment: It is very simple to implement in XSLT.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted what you've tried, here's what I would do and hopefully this will get you started.

What I would do is match text nodes whose parent has an `attrib` attribute value of "Old". Maybe a match like this:

```xml
text()[normalize-space()][../@attrib='Old']
```

Then I'd concatenate the value of the `attrib` attribute along with the value of the text() node. Something like (assuming XSLT 1.0 otherwise I'd probably use a `separator` attribute, `||`, or a text value template):

```xml
concat(../@attrib,'-',.)
```

Note: Even though we already know the value of the attrib attribute is going to be "Old", I didn't hardcode "Old-" in the concat. This is so that if "Old" needs to change it only needs to change in the match.

**Edit**

Here's what I would do...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()][../@attrib='Old']">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@attrib,'-',.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Working example: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyfAiD3

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Haley

I used `<xsl:value-of select="@attrib" separator="-"/>` but it's just replacing the value of the element. I did try to use concat as per your example but it's not getting and combining the attrib value "Old"

`<xsl:template match="*[@attrib='Old' and normalize-space(.)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@attrib,'-',.)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>`

result:
`<item attrib="Old">-value1</item>`

Comment: @demi - I added a full example.

Comment: @demi - Did my example help or are you still having trouble?

Comment: The last update you shared worked. Thank you @Daniel Haley